# Run hidden exe file from image (at image launch)

Tags: image, binding, exe, hidden-files

I'm trying to bind image file and .exe so when the image file is opened both will run. The image will appear and the exe will run.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: what kind of virus are you trying to do? :)

Comment: nothing in particular, its for educational study